# Delete folder using cmd 'amp' is not recognised as an internal or external command

Tags: windows, cmd, windows-10

I have a folder on my desktop, when I try to delete it, Windows 10 says it Could not find this item.

I tried to delete from cmd, but the folder name is bizarre...

```
Anne-Marie &amp; Rhodri&#039;s Album
```

So I tried..

```
rmdir /s /q Anne-Marie &amp; Rhodri&#039;s Album
```

But i get the error "amp" is not recognised as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

I get the same problem when trying to rename it first.

Comment: Quote it `rmdir /s /q "Anne-Marie &amp; Rhodri&#039;s Album"`

Comment: Thank you, that did something, the "not recognised" message doesn't appear any more, but now I get "The system cannot find the file specified" even though the folder is still there

Comment: Maybe you have spaces at the end of the folder name. Try with   `rmdir "\\?\%cd%\Anne-Marie &amp; Rhodri&#039;s Album "`

Comment: You could do `dir /X` which will give you the short names (8.3 format). You can then used the short name to delete the directory.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @MC ND it was spaces at the end of the file. Thank you!